# Parametrize the line in $\Bbb R^3$ that is determined by the intersection of the planes:

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

I am given two equations

\begin{alignat}{2}
x&+\phantom{0}y&\phantom{0}+z&=\phantom{0}4 \\
2x&+\phantom{0}y&\phantom{0}-2z\phantom{0}&=\phantom{0}4 \\
 \end{alignat}

I am wondering how to solve this as when I do -2R1 - R2 -> R2 I end up with

\begin{alignat}{2}
x&+\phantom{0}y&\phantom{0}+z&=\phantom{0}4 \\
0x&+\phantom{0}0&\phantom{0}-4z\phantom{0}&=\phantom{0}0 \\
 \end{alignat}

I know this is not correct but I am unable to solve this.

Comment: the second equation it should be $0x+3y-4z=-4$

Comment: You should have done -2R1 + R2 -> R2.

Comment: $-2R_1-R_2$ gives $-4x-2y=-12$. The row operation you actually performed (incorrectly) was $-2R_1+R_2\to R_2$.

Answer (score 1):

When you add to second row the first one times $-2$, what you get is$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x-y+z=4\\3y-4z=-4\end{array}\right.$$So, $y=\frac43z-\frac43$. Now, replace $y$ by $\frac43z-\frac43$ in the first equation, and you will get $x$ as a function of $z$.

Comment: My equations were wrong, x - y on both equations should have been x + y  hence how I got 0x +0y -4z for the second row